# See more button for php array

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

So I have been making a homelab dashboard, I need to know how I can add a responsive "show more" button after displaying my php array. I'm fairly new to development and it more as a hobby. Below is how I have it setup currently, but if I have more than 15 items in the torrent array it gets lengthy. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
<div class="row">
<!--Downloading Section-->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="info-box blue-bg">
        <h3>Downloading <span class="speeds">
        <?php
            if ($client == "qbittorent"){
                echo round(intval($global_info['dl_info_speed'])/1000, 2) . " kB/s";
            } elseif ($client == "transmission"){
                echo round(intval($global_info['downloadSpeed'])/1000, 2) . " kB/s";
            }
        ?>
        </span></h3>
        <?php
            if($torrents == null){
                echo "There was a problem fetching torrents.";
            } else {
                if ($client == "qbittorrent"){
                    foreach($torrents as $torrent){
                        if($torrent['state'] == "downloading"){
                            echo $torrent['name'] . "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($client == "transmission"){
                    foreach($torrents['torrents'] as $torrent){
                        if($torrent['status'] == "4"){
                            echo $torrent['name'] . "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div><!--/.info-box-->
</div><!--/.col-->
```

Comment: You can hide the output with CSS and add a button which reacts on a javascript to enlarge the hidden part.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this.

- AJAX: use javascript to detect when a button is clicked, then submit an ajax call to a page with the results, then add the results to the page
- Visible Toggle: Print out all the results, as you're doing now, but hide anything after 15 (ie. `style="display:none"`). And then use javascript to detect a button click, and toggle the visibility to show the hidden results.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have a "PHP Show More Button". PHP is executed server side, you need Javascript to achieve this.

You would use Javascript to execute an Ajax request to a PHP page that would generate the content you require for your "More Items" and then return it to the Javascript function to then append your HTML.